# Non technical installation of Unity app on iphone for testing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I don't have an iPhone so a friend has offered to test my Google Cardboard, Unity app. How can she test it without having to install Unity? I have found tutorials for testing on an iphone but nothing about how to send to a 3rd party, with no technical skills, to take a look. I have built the app for iOs and it is sitting on my machine. How do I get it onto her phone with the minimum of fuss?

thanks

Comment: The simplest way is to use TestFlight via App Store Connect.  You can also get her iPhone's UUID and add it to the app's provisioning profile on developer.apple.com so that you can send an ad-hoc build to them

Comment: brilliant - will investigate... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer was to do this in Testflight. Add their email to testflight, they will need to install it, then be offered the chance to install the app.